# How can I get notified of client disconnects?

Tags: java, sockets

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
try (
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
) {
  while (in.readLine() != null) {
    //do something
  }
  System.out.println("reach me if you can");
  socket.close();
}
```

Writing my Server/Client software, I tried to implement functionality to show number of current connections. But I realized that my server never gets the message when a client abruptly terminates; it just keeps waiting at `in.readLine()`. How should I ensure that a `Thread` created to handle a specific connection is not left running while the connection is dead?

Comment: [Watch this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1823461?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: @user2413972 So, what was your point? He didn't get the help he needed either. And I'm even more stranded than that guy because my `in.readLine();` doesn't react to client termination.

Comment: I have been writing network code. There were receipts -1 byte or exception.

Comment: You might be able to use TCP keepalive.

Comment: Why are you reading lnes and throwing them away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general TCP problem that the machine on one end of a connection can go away without any notification to the machine on the other end.  Machines are not *supposed* to do that, but it isn't always under their control.  The usual way for one end to avoid waiting forever for data in such a case, and / or to avoid being loaded down with dead connections, is to employ a timeout.

The general problem is bigger than you described, but you should be able to solve the particular part you asked about by invoking `setSoTimeout()` on the socket some time before you try to read from it. The socket will then throw an exception if your read attempt blocks for longer than the time you specify.  This setting persists for the lifetime of the socket (or until you set a different value), so you can apply it immediately after accepting the connection if you wish.

Be aware, however, that a sufficiently long period of simple client inactivity can also cause a timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Once the `control flow` or what's the correct term for that? is back to the Thread, is there not a simple way to check whether the client is still connected?

Comment: ServerSocket has a isClosed() method.

Comment: @Duston, `ServerSocket.isClosed()` is no help for this purpose, because no `ServerSocket` is (directly) involved in the read operation.  `Socket.isClosed()` is more relevant, but it isn't helpful either -- the whole point is that as far as the local computer is concerned, the socket *isn't* closed.  If it were properly closed, either before the read or while the read was blocking, then the read would throw an exception.

Comment: It is a general TCP feature that the machine can go away without notification.  It's questionable whether it's a problem, as it can be an advantage to allow connections to persist through network configuration changes and outages.

Comment: @WarrenDew, it can indeed be an advantage that maintaining a connection does not depend on continuous reachability, but it is always a problem when one machine genuinely drops the connection abruptly.  Since in that case it *cannot* resume using the connection, any resources on the other end devoted to serving that connection are wasted.